# wrong encoding in jaxrs post method

Tags: java, json, character-encoding, jax-rs

I'm having an Encoding problem when trying to consume an Arabic json message, however when producing the json in a get method I get the message right here is the code:

```
@Path("/json")
public class HelloJson {

@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public Track getTrackInJSON() {

    Track track = new Track();
    track.setTitle("الليله");
    track.setSinger("عمرو دياب");

    return track;

}

@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String result = new String (("Track saved : " + track).getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(result);
    return Response.status(201).entity(result).type("text/plain; charset=UTF-8").build();
}

}
```

you can try this webservice on the following link:
http://java7learning-khalidspace.rhcloud.com/rest/json/get
if asked for authentication use username admin and password admin

this link will return you a json with Arabic values without any Encoding problems.
now take this json message and use it in the post method using the following link: 
http://java7learning-khalidspace.rhcloud.com/rest/json/post
you can use the post method using the webservice tester from eclipse or any other webservice just insert the `content-type=application/json` and `authorization = Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=` as request headers and but the json in the request body.
the post method will return a massage with the arabic characters as "????"

please tell me what I'm missing and thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Already have you tried to send them with the escaped characters?:

```
{ 
    "title"  : "\u0627\u0644\u0644\u064A\u0644\u0647",
    "singer" : "\u0639\u0645\u0631\u0648 \u062F\u064A\u0627\u0628"
}
```

I get with this way using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) and your http://java7learning-khalidspace.rhcloud.com/rest/application.wadl:

```
Track saved : Track [title=الليله, singer=عمرو دياب]
```

Comment: thanks alot for your answer it was helpful but can I get these escaped characters form a user input. this web service is supposed to be accessed from a front-end application most likely an android application so how can I take the input from the user and generate it's escaped characters.